# My program doesn't excute even installed runtime package

Tags: c#, runtime, .net-core-3.1

I published my program(.net core 3.1 winform program). but it doesnt excuted even installed .net core 3.1 run-time package. so i install .net core 3.1 sdk package, it works.

**why i install sdk instead of run-time package?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem creating a single file by using app.config in the wrong way.
When app.config was used in the correct way, it was confirmed that it works normally only with the runtime sdk.
Previously, both *.dll.config and *.dll were required, but after correcting it, only *.dll.config worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

The software development kit (SDK) includes everything you need to build and run . NET Core applications, using command line tools and any editor (including Visual Studio). The runtime includes just the resources required to run existing